# Js div scroll to bottom in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a problem by writing the function scrollToBot. The function would be called by componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate. But the div doesn't scroll. I don't know what's wrong in this function. Must I ues JQuery to implement this function?

Thanks in advance.

```
scrollToBot(){
    console.log(this.textAreaDiv.offsetHeight); // 4000
    if(this.textAreaDiv.offsetHeight>3000){
        console.log("should scoll!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // showed
        this.textAreaDiv.scrollTop=2000;
    }
    console.log('run scrollTo'); // showed
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.scrollToBot();
}

componentDidUpdate(){
    this.scrollToBot();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work in React, since it uses Virtual DOM, to access the real DOM elements you need to use Refs as described in [React Documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your JSX use `ref` in order to access the dom element from the rest of your react component.

Example:

```
...
textAreaDiv: null

setInputRef(dom){
    this.textAreaDiv = dom
}

render(){
    <div ref={this.setInputRef}/>
}
```

`